# Why command line completion doesn't work anymore with ":>"?

Tags: command-line, 12.10, bash

I've got a file called (for example) myApp.log.

On a 12.04 system I could enter

```
:> my
```

followed by the tab key and the rest of the filename would be filled in (or if more than 1 file with a name that begins with "my" it would require additional letters until uniqueness was achieved).

Now I've upgraded to 12.10 and the filename expansion no longer works for `:>`.

filename expansion works for other commands as expected.

Has something changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something changed in `bash-completion`. Now you have to escape the colon (`:`).

```
\:> my
```